# Error de linter con importaciones en vscode

Tags: python-3.x, django, vscode, djangorestframework

Un saludo para todos

Estoy usando vscode para todas mi labores de programación, principalmente con python y Django.

Actualmente estoy creando un proyecto nuevo y por alguna razón tengo un mensaje de error al importar librerias de terceros, lo cual me hace mas lento el trabajo ya que no me muestra las sujerencias de archivos, funciones u objetos, dentro de la libreria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia en la imagen el environment está selecionado por el editor, la librería está instalada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien está configurada en el `settings.py`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los proyectos anteriores funciona bien, pero en este último que creé no.
No sé que mas hacer, hasta donde recuerdo todo esta bien configurado.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

Por alguna razon mi environmet estaba conectado con la instalación de python, las dependencias se guadaban allá.

```
/c/Program Files/Python/Python310/Lib/site-packages
```

Lo que hice fue desintalar las dependencias, borrar el environment y crear otro nuevo, despues instale nuevamente las dependencias.

Ahora si estan los paquetes instalados en `.env/Lib/site-packages`